# Firebase - WebSocket is closed before the connection is established.

Tags: firebase

Just starting out with Firebase (great concept BTW) and I notice in the Chrome console it reports "WebSocket is closed before the connection is established"

It still works but wondered why that might be happening - is it anything to be concerned about?

Interestingly it does state there is a successful websocket connection.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a known issue. The Firebase client attempts to establish a real-time connection to the Firebase servers using multiple methods. If one of those methods succeeds before the Websocket does, we cancel the Websocket and you see that warning. You can safely ignore the error.

Comment: How can we ignore error when its not displaying the data from the firebase and is not saving data to firebase server?

Comment: It takes 30 seconds for this message to appear. The data then shows up. This issue only occurs in Chrome, not Firefox, not IE.

Answer (score 1):

I've been troubleshooting this issue for weeks, and can reproduce it consistently. Sometimes I get the `WebSocket is closed` warning, other times it's an actual error:

> WebSocket connection to 'wss://s-usc1c-nss-214.firebaseio.com/.ws?v=5&ns=foo' failed: WebSocket opening handshake timed out

Had a long email chain with support. They stated "it shouldn't be that long to establish connection the way your app did" and that "it seems that this is outside the Google network, and without any further data, this is just probably just regular internet connectivity mayhem."

But I agree with @Xi Xiao above, that "freezing for 30secs is not an eligible solution." I've [created a GitHub Issue](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/540) detailing the problem and suggesting a couple solutions.

Comment: Any resolution? This is happening for me inside of an ionic application.

Answer (score 0):

This caused flakiness in my Cypress e2e tests.
As a temporary solution, I had to set `defaultCommandTimeout` to `35000` in Cypress config as specified in [Cypress docs](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/configuration.html#Timeouts).