# firebase listener callback sometimes takes too long to fire

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have been using firebase realtime database to store really simple data. Listeners are set on the complementary lifecycle events. Everything works okay most of the time. Rarely the callback snapshot takes longer than its average 1-2 seconds but it eventually does respond after 30 or 40 seconds. This is, however, is not a network issue and only occurs on windows clients.

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.folderRef = db.ref(`folders/${this.props.user}`)
    this.listRef = db.ref(`lists/${this.props.user}`)
    this.folderListener = this.folderRef.on('value', (snapshot) => {
        //this won't fire randomly
        this.props.getFolderTree(snapshot.val())
    })
    this.listListener = this.listRef.on('value', (snapshot) => {
        //this won't fire randomly
        this.props.getList(snapshot.val())
    })
}

componentWillUnmount() {
    if (this.folderListener) {
        this.folderRef.off('value', this.folderListener)
        this.folderListener = null
    }
    if (this.listListener) {
        this.listRef.off('value', this.listListener)
        this.listListener = null
    }
}
```

I wondered if someone who had similar behaviour on firebase value callbacks could share the same insight on how they resolved the issue.

Edit: identical to [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50589809/firebase-database-looses-websocket-connection-which-results-in-delays)

Comment: If you want a discussion about Firebase APIs, Stack Overflow isn't the right place to start that.  Consider instead a discussion forum such as Reddit or firebase-talk.

Comment: I checked it out but it says do not use this group for Questions involving code. on firebase-talk.

Comment: Your question is really just that listeners are taking longer than expected.  It's OK to show a little bit of code, if you think that helps explain yourself, but there could be any number of reasons that the listener triggers slower than you expect, and it almost certainly won't be because of your code.

Comment: I've encountered the same issue before and the issue was that I was doing an update operation of huge size which I suppose halted all other firebase callbacks. I decided to store that part of data on cloud storage instead of firebase which resolved the issue back then. I wanted to know if there are any other cases similar to this that someone encountered which could make callbacks not respond.