# How to stop browser console logging of the connection state for Realtime Database?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, websocket

I've just added handling of connection and disconnection to my WebRTC application that use firebase for signaling.

The problem is that when I disconnect the internet I got lot of errors from firebase.

```
WebSocketConnection.ts:169 WebSocket connection to 'wss://s-usc1c-nss-219.firebaseio.com/.ws?v=5&ls=gg16vFmqFzo8cwtkBHygyI9EQEaV8wTm&ns=jcubic-webrtc' failed: Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_INTERNET_DISCONNECTED
BrowserPollConnection.ts:720 GET https://jcubic-webrtc.firebaseio.com/.lp?start=t&ser=49042678&cb=1&v=5&ls=gg16vFmqFzo8cwtkBHygyI9EQEaV8wTm net::ERR_INTERNET_DISCONNECTED
BrowserPollConnection.ts:720 GET https://jcubic-webrtc.firebaseio.com/.lp?start=t&ser=49042678&cb=1&v=5&ls=gg16vFmqFzo8cwtkBHygyI9EQEaV8wTm net::ERR_INTERNET_DISCONNECTED
BrowserPollConnection.ts:720 GET https://jcubic-webrtc.firebaseio.com/.lp?start=t&ser=49042678&cb=1&v=5&ls=gg16vFmqFzo8cwtkBHygyI9EQEaV8wTm net::ERR_INTERNET_DISCONNECTED
BrowserPollConnection.ts:720 GET https://jcubic-webrtc.firebaseio.com/.lp?start=t&ser=49042678&cb=1&v=5&ls=gg16vFmqFzo8cwtkBHygyI9EQEaV8wTm net::ERR_INTERNET_DISCONNECTED
```

it works when I connect back, but I would like to get rid of those errors. Is it possible?

Comment: [maybe relevant](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12432399/4051471)

Comment: What behavior of your app are you trying to change?

Comment: @DougStevenson everything is working, I want to get rid of the errors in console.

Comment: This sounds like a feature request for the Firebase Realtime Database SDK.  https://github.com/firebase/firebase-android-sdk/tree/master/firebase-database