# Unable to connect to Firebase(JS)

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to connect my web app to firebase and i'm following the instructions as per the official documentation, it seems the connection is established as I do not see any errors in the console, but i'm unable to write data to the database

HTML:

```
      <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.5.2/firebase-app.js"></script>

      <script src="main.js"></script>
```

JS:

```
submitBtn.onclick = function () {
var firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "-------------",
    authDomain: "--------------",
    databaseURL: "------------",
    projectId: "----------",
    storageBucket: "--------",
    messagingSenderId: "---------------",
    appId: "---------------"
};
// Initialize Firebase
firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
console.log(firebaseConfig);

var database = firebase.database();
var ref = database.ref("myTickets");
var data = {
    name: "First User",
    score: 43
}

ref.push(data)
}
```

For the time being I hard coded the data that I want to add and upon the button click it should update the data in the database but at times I am getting "main.js:33 Uncaught TypeError: firebase.database is not a function"

I tried changing the gstatic link to firebase.js but still getting the same error.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

Add the `firebase database` script also to be able to use `database()`:

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.5.2/firebase-database.js"></script>
```

You can find the full list of firebase products to add here:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#libraries-cdn

Comment: hi, I did that but I get the following error now errors                                                 
.ts:101 Uncaught FirebaseError: Firebase: Firebase App named '[DEFAULT]' already exists (app/duplicate-app). I do not have any duplicate app

Comment: you are initialising twice `firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);`

Answer (score 1):

As you see in the [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#add-sdks-initialize), there are two ways to add Firebase SDKs:

### 1. Include the entire Firebase JavaScript SDK

This not recommended for production apps

```
  <body>
    <!-- Insert this script at the bottom of the HTML, but before you use any Firebase services -->

    <!-- Add the entire Firebase JavaScript SDK -->
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.5.2/firebase.js"></script>
  </body>
```

### 2. Include only specific Firebase products

```
<body>
  <!-- Insert these scripts at the bottom of the HTML, but before you use any Firebase services -->

  <!-- Firebase App (the core Firebase SDK) is always required and must be listed first -->
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.5.2/firebase-app.js"></script>

  <!-- Add Firebase products that you want to use -->
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.5.2/firebase-auth.js"></script>
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.5.2/firebase-database.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: I am getting this error: WebSocketConnection.ts:366 WebSocket connection to 'wss://s-usc1c-nss-249.firebaseio.com/.ws?v=5&s=uINs4cd9gP7ctZeaReP6SUlD27ppimNb&ns=system1-a64ba' failed: **WebSocket is closed before the connection is established.**

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12421993/firebase-websocket-is-closed-before-the-connection-is-established.

Answer (score 0):

Refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38248723/firebase-database-is-not-a-function) link which contains a discussion related to same issue. Looks like you have missed adding some firebase libraries(I havent tested your code though)

Also you **should not post your API key** in stackoverflow or any public website. People can misuse your API keys. You should change them immediately.